# Questions about why a player wears a certain jersey number/name

Tags: discussion

There have been a couple of questions in the last few days about why players wear their jersey number/name.

- [Jersey number for Kobe Bryant](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2122/jersey-number-for-kobe-bryant/2124#2124)
- https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2131/jersey-number-for-lebron-james
- [Jersey name for World Peace](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/jersey-name-for-world-peace)

When I saw the first one, I almost threw a close flag at it. Then I thought that if I could find credible information about why Kobe's jersey numbers were 8 and 24, I'd post an answer and call it good. I found a sources from years ago speculating on his jersey numbers and decided to post an answer, waiting to see if others closed the question.

Now the second question has popped up and I'm wondering if we accidentally set a precedent for these types of questions. I feel that most of the time, these answers are going to be answered with either speculation or short answer like "That was his number in high school" or "That's the player's favorite number."

There is now a close vote on the Lebron question. My inclination is to say we should close these types of questions since that was my first instinct on the Kobe question. Should we be closing these questions or letting them stay open?

Comment: I have the same thought. I'm surprised the Kobe question is at +3/-2 and Lebron's at 0/-3 (with a close vote). I thought the questions were weak, at best, to begin with...unless a player comes right out and say it (which isn't definitively the case for either player), the answers would be speculatory at best.

Comment: That was my thought process. I'm not sure where that leaves us except to close any further questions like this and maybe retroactively close the Kobe question to make sure we're consistent.

Comment: I agree, but let's see if the questions get any additional close votes before I close them. This is where the community speaks up.

Comment: Guess I'll add my voice.

Comment: @Sancho Ironically a question that I answered.

Comment: Although unrelated, I think questions like [this](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2209/los-angeles-lakers-info) may fall into the same pattern of having questions about other team's histories...how would we deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

Only one of these 3 questions is actually valid.

Questions about *why* a player wears a certain number are not useful questions. They are mainly speculation, and if they aren't (ie the player has given the reasons) they are still rather uninteresting questions.

Questions about what Jersey number a player wears are redundant with Wikipedia or a relevant reference site for that sport and should be easily obtained there and closed here. Questions about why a player wears a number are speculative and not constructive and should be closed as such.

However, the Ron Artest/Metta World Peace question actually has a good bit of validity to it. Because the player wears a different name on his Jersey than he is sometimes announced as (announcers and writers often still use his given name instead of his legal name), it make sense to ask this out of confusion.

Relieving confusion about this (and similar things like the Chad OchoCinco/Chat Johnson, or Mike Stanton/Giancarlo Stanton sitautions) are fair game. Answers there should cover the name change and if information is available may delve into what the player says about why (although this is not necessary).

Comment: I agree with the Artest (aka "World Peace") question. If the OP doesn't follow NBA, it would be rather hard to figure out who the player is, and why the hell would someone have "World Peace" as a name on his jersey.

Comment: @wax eagle: I'm mainly playing devil's advocate here, but "rather uninteresting questions" is pretty subjective don't you think? :)  On the flip side, I'm probably getting into a circular argument with that question.

Comment: yes, it's somewhat subjective, perhaps a better choice of words was "rather unanswerable questions." Uninteresting is sort of in the "nothing definitive" is uninteresting to SE's Q&A model line of thought.

Comment: Agreed, and good point.